# Date difference in minutes in Python

Tags: python, datetime

How do I calculate the difference in time in minutes for the following timestamp in Python?

```
2010-01-01 17:31:22
2010-01-03 17:31:22
```

Comment: not sure if it is possible, but you should change your accepted answer since the one you picked doesn't work in all cases, and might cause people problems.

Answer (score -46, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
d1 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-01 17:31:22', fmt)
d2 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-03 17:31:22', fmt)

print (d2-d1).days * 24 * 60
```

Comment: This answer works only if the 2 times are at the exact same second (different days)

Answer (score 188):

```
minutes_diff = (datetime_end - datetime_start).total_seconds() / 60.0
```

Comment: Great and simple answer; I'd add the caveat that this assumes that `datetime_end` and `datetime_start` are already parsed into `datetime` objects. The substraction produces a `timedelta` instance.

Comment: This worked for me with the addition of .dt. That is, 

`minutes_diff = (datetime_end - datetime_start).dt.total_seconds() / 60.0`

Answer (score 111):

[RSabet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788871/date-difference-in-minutes-in-python/2790177#2790177) doesn't work in cases where the dates don't have the same exact time.

Original problem:

```
from datetime import datetime

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
d1 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-01 17:31:22', fmt)
d2 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-03 17:31:22', fmt)

daysDiff = (d2-d1).days
print daysDiff
> 2

# Convert days to minutes
minutesDiff = daysDiff * 24 * 60

print minutesDiff
> 2880
```

d2-d1 gives you a datetime.timedelta and when you use days it will only show you the days in the timedelta. In this case it works fine, but if you would have the following.

```
from datetime import datetime

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
d1 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-01 16:31:22', fmt)
d2 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-03 20:15:14', fmt)

daysDiff = (d2-d1).days
print daysDiff
> 2

# Convert days to minutes
minutesDiff = daysDiff * 24 * 60

print minutesDiff
> 2880  # that is wrong
```

It would have still given you the same answer since it still returns 2 for days; it ignores the hour, min and second from the timedelta.

A better approach would be to convert the dates to a common format and then do the calculation. The easiest way to do this is to convert them to Unix timestamps. Here is the code to do that.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
d1 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-01 17:31:22', fmt)
d2 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-03 20:15:14', fmt)

# Convert to Unix timestamp
d1_ts = time.mktime(d1.timetuple())
d2_ts = time.mktime(d2.timetuple())

# They are now in seconds, subtract and then divide by 60 to get minutes.
print int(d2_ts-d1_ts) / 60
> 3043  # Much better
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, I have two values that are typically 50-100 seconds apart, but when I use this it returns a value somewhere in the range of -17K to -18K. any idea why this may be? (I'm using the code exactly as written, except the given dates are different).

Comment: `time.mktime()` may take into account the changes in the local utc offset on some platforms (it also may fail if input is an ambiguous local time such as during a end-of-DST transition). To get consistent results on all platforms, you could use `pytz` timezones (such as returned by `tzlocal.get_localzone()` call) to get aware datetime objects -- to get the correct elapsed time (ignoring leap seconds).

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. Honestly, datetime is not a very user friendly module

Comment: This gets fail if `d1 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-01 17:31:22', fmt)` and `d2 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-01 18:31:22', fmt)` giving 0, as there is not any day difference and only having minutes difference.

Answer (score 19):

In case someone doesn't realize it, one way to do this would be to combine Christophe and RSabet's answers:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
d1 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-01 17:31:22', fmt)
d2 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-03 20:15:14', fmt)

diff = d2 -d1
diff_minutes = (diff.days * 24 * 60) + (diff.seconds/60)

print(diff_minutes)
> 3043
```

Comment: this method fails if the utc corresponding to `d1` is different from the one for `d2`. To take into account the utc offset, see the solution in [@Ken Cochrane's answer and my comment there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6879077/4279)

Answer (score 7):

To calculate with a different time date:

```
from datetime import datetime

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
d1 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-01 16:31:22', fmt)
d2 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-03 20:15:14', fmt)

diff = d2-d1
diff_minutes = diff.seconds/60
```

Comment: This method is not correct, it ignores the difference in days.

Answer (score 5):

Use `datetime.strptime()` to parse into datetime instances, and then compute the difference, and finally convert the difference into minutes.

Answer (score 3):

The result depends on the timezone that corresponds to the input time strings.

The simplest case if both dates use the same utc offset:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time_format = "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"
dt1 = datetime.strptime("2010-01-01 17:31:22", time_format)
dt2 = datetime.strptime("2010-01-03 17:31:22", time_format)
print((dt2 - dt1) // timedelta(minutes=1)) # minutes
```

If your Python version doesn't support `td // timedelta`; replace it with `int(td.total_seconds() // 60)`.

If the input time is in the local timezone that might have different utc offset at different times e.g., it has daylight saving time then you should make `dt1`, `dt2` into aware datetime objects before finding the difference, to take into account the possible changes in the utc offset.

The portable way to make an aware local datetime objects is to use `pytz` timezones:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import timedelta
import tzlocal # $ pip install tzlocal

local_tz = tzlocal.get_localzone() # get pytz timezone
aware_dt1, aware_dt2 = map(local_tz.localize, [dt1, dt2])
td  = aware_dt2 - aware_dt1 # elapsed time
```

If either `dt1` or `dt2` correspond to an ambiguous time then the default `is_dst=False` is used to disambiguate. You could set `is_dst=None` to raise an exception for ambiguous or non-existent local times instead.

If you can't install 3rd party modules then [`time.mktime()` could be used from @Ken Cochrane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6879077/4279) that can find the correct utc offset on some platforms for some dates in some timezones -- if you don't need a consistent (but perhaps wrong) result then it is much better than doing `dt2 - dt1` with naive datetime objects that always fails if the corresponding utc offsets are different.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to find the difference between timestamps that are in pandas columns, the the answer is fairly simple.
If you need it in days or seconds then

```
# For difference in days:
df['diff_in_days']=(df['timestamp2'] - df['timestamp1']).dt.days
# For difference in seconds
df['diff_in_seconds']=(df['timestamp2'] - df['timestamp1']).dt.seconds
```

Now minute is tricky as dt.minute works only on datetime64[ns] dtype.
whereas the column generated from subtracting two datetimes has format

```
AttributeError: 'TimedeltaProperties' object has no attribute 'm8'
```

So like mentioned by many above to get the actual value of the difference in minute you have to do:

```
df['diff_in_min']=df['diff_in_seconds']/60
```

But if just want the difference between the minute parts of the  two timestamps then do the following

```
#convert the timedelta to datetime and then extract minute
df['diff_in_min']=(pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp2']-df['timestamp1'])).dt.minute
```

You can also read the article https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html
and see section 8.1.2 you'll see the read only attributes are only seconds,days and milliseconds. And this settles why the minute function doesn't work directly.

Answer (score 1):

In Other ways to get difference between date;

```
import dateutil.parser
import datetime

timeDifference = current_date - dateutil.parser.parse(last_sent_date)
time_difference_in_minutes = (int(timeDifference.days) * 24 * 60) + int((timeDifference.seconds) / 60)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
From datetime import datetime
dt_1 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-01 17:31:22', '%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S')
dt_2 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-03 17:31:22', '%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S')
           
time_delta_obj = (dt_2 - dt_1)
diff_in_mins = int(time_delta_obj.total_seconds()/60)
print(diff_in_mins)
```

Please note that in python, difference between two dates returns a time delta object. From there, we calculate how many minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As was kind of said already, you need to use `datetime.datetime's` `strptime` method:

```
from datetime import datetime

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
d1 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-01 17:31:22', fmt)
d2 = datetime.strptime('2010-01-03 17:31:22', fmt)

daysDiff = (d2-d1).days

# convert days to minutes
minutesDiff = daysDiff * 24 * 60

print minutesDiff
```

Answer (score 0):

there is also a sneak way with pandas:

`pd.to_timedelta(x) - pd.to_timedelta(y)`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using divmod,

```
minutes = divmod((end_date - start_date).total_seconds(), 60)[0]
```