# Python: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'datetime'

Tags: python, strptime

I am using this code:

```
def calcDateDifferenceInMinutes(end_date,start_date):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    start_date_dt = datetime.strptime(start_date, fmt)
    end_date_dt = datetime.strptime(end_date, fmt)

# convert to unix timestamp
start_date_ts = time.mktime(start_date_dt.timetuple())
end_date_ts   = time.mktime(end_date_dt.timetuple())

# they are now in seconds, subtract and then divide by 60 to get minutes.
return (int(end_date_ts-start_date_ts) / 60)
```

from this question: [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788871/python-date-difference-in-minutes/6879077#6879077)

But I'm getting this message:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'datetime'

I've reviewed similar questions but don't see any alternatives other than to do something like:

```
start_date_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, fmt)
```

Here's the full trace:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tabbed_all_cols.py", line
> 156, in <module>
>     trip_calculated_duration = calcDateDifferenceInMinutes (end_datetime,start_datetime)   File "tabbed_all_cols.py", line 41, in
> calcDateDifferenceInMinutes
>     start_date_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, fmt) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'datetime'
```

And line 41 is:

> ```
> start_date_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, fmt)
> ```

Can someone shed light on what I'm missing?

**New Update**: I'm still trying to figure this out. I see that version is important. I am using version 2.7 and am importing datetime.

I don't think I am setting the string date back to a string, which is what I think people are suggesting below.

Thanks

Comment: Somewhere upstream, you must have done `datetime = "some string"`

Comment: Your title and your question have different error messages.  Which is it?

Comment: Hi all: Here's the call to the method:            duration = calcDateDifferenceInMinutes (tend_datetime,start_datetime). And I am passing in a these as strings.

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace. It will tell you what line has the error

Comment: '@zondo - Yes, I've updated my title to reflect the error I'm getting. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: is there indentation typo in your code? I suppose all the lines belong to the function?

Comment: **Your exception does not match the code posted**. Please provide **all** the code in one block. Perhaps you should share what you're actually trying to achieve

Comment: @Jazzmine see my last comment - you need to provide **all** of your code and formatted correctly

Answer (score 8):

When you get an error like `<str> object has no attribute X`, that means that somewhere you are doing something like `some_object.X`. It also means that `some_object` is a string. Since it doesn't have the attribute, it typically means you are assuming that `some_object` is something else.

The full error message will tell you what line is causing the problem. In your case, it is this:

```
start_date_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, fmt) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'datetime'
```

The only object here that is accessing `datetime` is the first `datetime`. That means that the first `datetime` is a string, and you're assuming it represents a module.

If you were to print out `datetime` (eg: `print("datetime is:", datetime)`) I'm sure you would see a string.

That means that somewhere else in your code you are overwriting `datetime` by setting it to a string (eg: `datetime = "some string"`)

Comment: In my case, it was because I had unwisely created another variable called "time" that contained the current time I was getting from a GPS unit. The code thought I was attempting to access this variable (which was a string), instead of the time class.