# Time difference within group by objects in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, difference, data-science, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
from    to         datetime              other
-------------------------------------------------
11      1     2016-11-06 22:00:00          -
11      1     2016-11-06 20:00:00          -
11      1     2016-11-06 15:45:00          -
11      12    2016-11-06 15:00:00          -
11      1     2016-11-06 12:00:00          -
11      18    2016-11-05 10:00:00          -
11      12    2016-11-05 10:00:00          -
12      1     2016-10-05 10:00:59          -
12      3     2016-09-06 10:00:34          -
```

I want to groupby "from" and then "to" columns and then sort the "datetime" in descending order and then finally want to calculate the time difference within these grouped by objects between the current time and the next time. For eg, in this case,
I would like to have a dataframe like the following:

```
from    to     timediff in minutes                                          others
11      1            120
11      1            255
11      1            225
11      1            0 (preferrably subtract this date from the epoch)
11      12           300
11      12           0
11      18           0
12      1            25
12      3            0
```

I can't get my head around figuring this out!! Is there a way out for this?
Any help will be much much appreciated!!
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: [Does this post help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2788871/6912791)? It's just a simple way to compare DateTime objects. I am not extremely familiar with dataframes, but If I remember correctly you can loop over certain columns.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
df.assign(
    timediff=df.sort_values(
        'datetime', ascending=False
    ).groupby(['from', 'to']).datetime.diff(-1).dt.seconds.div(60).fillna(0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

I think you need:

`groupby` with `apply` [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html), convert `Timedelta` to minutes by [`seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.seconds.html) and floor division `60`

`fillna` and `sort_index`, remove level `2` in index

```
df = df.groupby(['from','to']).datetime
       .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().diff().dt.seconds // 60)
       .fillna(0)
       .sort_index()
       .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
       .reset_index(name='timediff in minutes')

print (df)

   from  to  timediff in minutes 
0    11   1                 120.0
1    11   1                 255.0
2    11   1                 225.0
3    11   1                   0.0
4    11  12                 300.0
5    11  12                   0.0
6    11  18                   0.0
7    12   3                   0.0
8    12   3                   0.0
```

---

```
df = df.join(df.groupby(['from','to'])
               .datetime
               .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().diff().dt.seconds // 60)
               .fillna(0)
               .reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True)
               .rename('timediff in minutes'))
print (df)
   from  to            datetime other  timediff in minutes
0    11   1 2016-11-06 22:00:00     -                120.0
1    11   1 2016-11-06 20:00:00     -                255.0
2    11   1 2016-11-06 15:45:00     -                225.0
3    11  12 2016-11-06 15:00:00     -                300.0
4    11   1 2016-11-06 12:00:00     -                  0.0
5    11  18 2016-11-05 10:00:00     -                  0.0
6    11  12 2016-11-05 10:00:00     -                  0.0
7    12   3 2016-10-05 10:00:59     -                  0.0
8    12   3 2016-09-06 10:00:34     -                  0.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!This works but I also wanted the "other" column to remain as it is!

Comment: Ok, I add solution for it.

Answer (score 14):

Almost as above, but without `apply`:

```
result = df.sort_values(['from','to','datetime'])\
           .groupby(['from','to'])['datetime']\
           .diff().dt.seconds.fillna(0)
```

Comment: I've found using .apply() as in jezrael's answer just slightly faster than calling .diff() directly (e.g. %timeit on 1000 rows, 100 loops, best of 3: 10.9ms/loop with apply and 11.1ms/loop without apply)

Comment: ```
.astype('timedelta64[m]').fillna(0)
```

instead of the 
```
.dt.seconds.fillna(0)
```

is also comfortable