# Calculate difference between two datetimes odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo-10

Working on Odoo10, i need to calculate the difference between two fields of datetime type, start and finish, i need the difference to be in **minutes.** how can i do that ?

Comment: maybe you can use this : https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-to-calculate-difference-bitween-two-dates-31486

Comment: @DavidS i need datetime not just date ! and i need it in hours not in days

Comment: I see, but I hope you can solve this after that help, just you should change the `fmt` and the `days`

Comment: But you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788871/date-difference-in-minutes-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this example:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

@api.one 
@api.depends('start_field','finish_field')
def _total_minutes(self):
    if self.start_field and self.finish_field:
        start_dt = fields.Datetime.from_string(self.start_field)
        finish_dt = fields.Datetime.from_string(self.finish_field)
        difference = relativedelta(finish_dt, start_dt)
        days = difference.days
        hours = difference.hours
        minutes = difference.minutes
        seconds = 0
```

Comment: thanks a lot! so clear, complete and straightforward!