# How to find duration between two time difference in python dataframe

Tags: python

I have raw data like this want to find the difference between this two time in mint .....problem is data which is in data frame...
source:

```
   start time   end time
0   08:30:00    17:30:00
1   11:00:00    17:30:00
2   08:00:00    21:30:00
3   19:30:00    22:00:00
4   19:00:00    00:00:00
5   08:30:00    15:30:00
```

Need a output like this:

```
duration
 540mint
 798mint
 162mint
 1140mint
 420mint
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date difference in minutes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788871/date-difference-in-minutes-in-python)

Comment: How are you calculating the time differences? 08:30:00 - 17:30:00 = -9 hours, not 120 minutes.

Comment: i wrote output for example only.

Comment: If you're going to show an example I would suggest it be representative of the actual correct output.

Comment: Your input is unclear. When you say dataframe, do you mean pandas? If so, the question should be tagged accordingly.

Comment: Also, please clarify, if you want a solution in R or in Python.

Comment: From `19:00:00` to `00:00:00` is normally only 5 hours? i.e. 300 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output seems to be incorrect. That aside, we can use base R's `difftime`:

```
transform(
    df,
    duration = difftime(
        strptime(end.time, format = "%H:%M:%S"),
        strptime(start.time, format = "%H:%M:%S"),
        units = "mins"))
#  start.time end.time   duration
#0   08:30:00 17:30:00   540 mins
#1   11:00:00 17:30:00   390 mins
#2   08:00:00 21:30:00   810 mins
#3   19:30:00 22:00:00   150 mins
#4   19:00:00 00:00:00 -1140 mins
#5   08:30:00 15:30:00   420 mins
```

or as a `difftime` vector

```
with(df, difftime(
    strptime(end.time, format = "%H:%M:%S"),
    strptime(start.time, format = "%H:%M:%S"),
    units = "mins"))
#Time differences in mins
#[1]   540   390   810   150 -1140   420
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "   'start time'   'end time'
0   08:30:00    17:30:00
1   11:00:00    17:30:00
2   08:00:00    21:30:00
3   19:30:00    22:00:00
4   19:00:00    00:00:00
5   08:30:00    15:30:00", header = T, row.names = 1)
```

Comment: This is a Python question. Not sure, why you suggest a solution in R.

Comment: @Mr.T it was tagged as an R question at first. Check the edits.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'start time':['08:30:00','11:00:00','08:00:00','19:30:00','19:00:00','08:30:00'],'end time':['17:30:00','17:30:00','21:30:00','22:00:00','00:00:00','15:30:00']},columns=['start time','end time'])

df
Out[355]:
  start time  end time
0   08:30:00  17:30:00
1   11:00:00  17:30:00
2   08:00:00  21:30:00
3   19:30:00  22:00:00
4   19:00:00  00:00:00
5   08:30:00  15:30:00

(pd.to_datetime(df['end time']) - pd.to_datetime(df['start time'])).dt.seconds/60
Out[356]:
0    540.0
1    390.0
2    810.0
3    150.0
4    300.0
5    420.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, definitely [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) is what you need here. Specifically, the `strptime` function, which parses a string into a time object.

```
from datetime import datetime
s1 = '10:33:26'
s2 = '11:15:49' # for example
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
```

That gets you a `timedelta` object that contains the difference between the two times. You can do whatever you want with that, e.g. converting it to seconds or adding it to another `datetime`.

This will return a negative result if the end time is earlier than the start time, for example `s1 = 12:00:00` and `s2 = 05:00:00`. If you want the code to assume the interval crosses midnight in this case (i.e. it should assume the end time is never earlier than the start time), you can add the following lines to the above code:

```
if tdelta.days < 0:
    tdelta = timedelta(days=0,
                seconds=tdelta.seconds, microseconds=tdelta.microseconds)
```

(of course you need to include `from datetime import timedelta` somewhere). Thanks to J.F. Sebastian for pointing out this use case.

Comment: see [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/how-to-calculate-the-time-interval-between-two-time-strings/3096984#3096984)