# Generating list of 5 minute interval between two times

Tags: python, timedelta

I have the following strings:

```
start = "07:00:00"
end = "17:00:00"
```

How can I generate a list of 5 minute interval between those times, ie

```
["07:00:00","07:05:00",...,"16:55:00","17:00:00"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me, I'm sure you can figure out how to put the results in the list instead of printing them out:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> start = "07:00:00"
>>> end = "17:00:00"
>>> delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
>>> start = datetime.datetime.strptime( start, '%H:%M:%S' )
>>> end = datetime.datetime.strptime( end, '%H:%M:%S' )
>>> t = start
>>> while t <= end :
...     print datetime.datetime.strftime( t, '%H:%M:%S')
...     t += delta
... 
07:00:00
07:05:00
07:10:00
07:15:00
07:20:00
07:25:00
07:30:00
07:35:00
07:40:00
07:45:00
07:50:00
07:55:00
08:00:00
08:05:00
08:10:00
08:15:00
08:20:00
08:25:00
08:30:00
08:35:00
08:40:00
08:45:00
08:50:00
08:55:00
09:00:00
09:05:00
09:10:00
09:15:00
09:20:00
09:25:00
09:30:00
09:35:00
09:40:00
09:45:00
09:50:00
09:55:00
10:00:00
10:05:00
10:10:00
10:15:00
10:20:00
10:25:00
10:30:00
10:35:00
10:40:00
10:45:00
10:50:00
10:55:00
11:00:00
11:05:00
11:10:00
11:15:00
11:20:00
11:25:00
11:30:00
11:35:00
11:40:00
11:45:00
11:50:00
11:55:00
12:00:00
12:05:00
12:10:00
12:15:00
12:20:00
12:25:00
12:30:00
12:35:00
12:40:00
12:45:00
12:50:00
12:55:00
13:00:00
13:05:00
13:10:00
13:15:00
13:20:00
13:25:00
13:30:00
13:35:00
13:40:00
13:45:00
13:50:00
13:55:00
14:00:00
14:05:00
14:10:00
14:15:00
14:20:00
14:25:00
14:30:00
14:35:00
14:40:00
14:45:00
14:50:00
14:55:00
15:00:00
15:05:00
15:10:00
15:15:00
15:20:00
15:25:00
15:30:00
15:35:00
15:40:00
15:45:00
15:50:00
15:55:00
16:00:00
16:05:00
16:10:00
16:15:00
16:20:00
16:25:00
16:30:00
16:35:00
16:40:00
16:45:00
16:50:00
16:55:00
17:00:00
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try**:

```
# import modules
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Create starting and end datetime object from string
start = datetime.strptime("07:00:00", "%H:%M:%S")
end = datetime.strptime("17:00:00", "%H:%M:%S")

# min_gap
min_gap = 5

# compute datetime interval
arr = [(start + timedelta(hours=min_gap*i/60)).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
       for i in range(int((end-start).total_seconds() / 60.0 / min_gap))]
print(arr)
# ['07:00:00', '07:05:00', '07:10:00', '07:15:00', '07:20:00', '07:25:00', '07:30:00', ..., '16:55:00']
```

**Explanations**:

1. First, you need to convert `string` date to datetime object. The [strptime](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) does it!
2. Then, we will find the number of minutes between the starting date and the ending datetime. This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788871/date-difference-in-minutes-in-python) solved it! We can do it like this :

```
(end-start).total_seconds() / 60.0
```

However, in our case, we only want to iterate every `n` minutes. So, in our `loop`, we need to divide it by `n`.

Also, as we will iterate over this number of minutes, we need to convertit to `int` for the `for` loop. That results in:

```
int((end-start).total_seconds() / 60.0 / min_gap)
```

3. Then, on each element of our loop, we will add the number of minutes to the initial datetime. The [tiemdelta](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) function has been designed for. As parameter, we specify the number of hours we want to add : `min_gap*i/60`.
4. Finally, we convert this `datetime` object back to a string object using the [strftime](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).

Comment: `start` and `end` are strings. are you going to parse them somehow?